# Sending a string over Python server to C# client returns a number of the chars in the string

Tags: c#, python, sockets

So I've been trying to create a simple chat program with python, but it's a combination of Python and C#... The server is built entirely out of Python and the client is C#. I use sockets for both of them. Data communication works 100%. When I click 'Connect' on the client, it connects and sends this message into the stream.

```
byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { };
sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NEW_CONN|");
clientSock.Send(sendBytes);
```

The server receives this and passes it through to a "accepting" method. The reason I won't show this part is because it works 100%. The problem lies within Server to Client. I don't know if it's a cross-platform problem, but I sure as hell want to find out. Here is the Python server code (for the "parse" method - accept data from the client and respond):

```
def parseData(sock, message) :
splitString = message.split('|')

if splitString[0] == "NEW_CONN":
    sendString = "CONN_A|"
    sock.send(sendString)  
    CONNECTION_LIST.append(sock)
    print "Client connected: " + str(sock.getpeername())
```

Now, when the client receives this message, it is simply "7". In other words, the total number of chars that make up sendString. It isn't a client conversion issue, because I've tested outputting the string like this (serverside):

```
print str(sock.send(sendString))
```

That bit of code outputs "7" as well. What have I done wrong?
*OTHER INFO:
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 #Buffer amount variable

Receiving function:

```
data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
parseData(sock, data)
```

You guys have been such a great help in the past. I just want to say thanks!

Comment: You say the client is C#, so where's the C# code for the receiving side? You're most likely looking at the result of `Socket.Receive` which returns the number of bytes received (not the "bytes received"). The bytes received will be in the byte array you provided to the Receive method.

Comment: Yes! I am using that! My receive method is:
const int bufferSize = 256;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
Parse(Convert.ToString(clientSock.Receive(buffer)));

What do I have to do from here to get my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments in the question, here's an example of how to parse the received bytes:

```
int numReceived = clientSock.Receive(buffer);
string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, numReceived);
```